# Key error in shuffled mini-batches for CNN implementation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conv-neural-network

I am trying to modify a CNN trained on MNIST data to work with my data.  I'm not very familiar with Python's data structures and have hit a roadblock.  Any suggestions for resolving this issue are appreciated.

This is the batching code that is causing a key error issue.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# training data modified to add column labels; label, pixel0, pixel1, ...
train = pd.read_csv("/Users/rebeccaschley/data/train-data3.txt")
# extract left-most columns containing labels from each data set
a = train.label
# convert to np arrays in order to use reshape method
train_labels = a.to_frame()
# remove label column and extract pixel values only from training and testing data
train_pixels = train.drop('label', 1).values

IMG_SIZE=16
x_trainr = np.array(train_pixels).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)

batch_size = 250  
    
# for training
def batch_data(source, target, batch_size):

    # Shuffle data
    shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(target)))
    source = source[shuffle_indices]
    target = target[shuffle_indices]

    for batch_i in range(0, len(source)//batch_size):
        start_i = batch_i * batch_size
        source_batch = source[start_i:start_i + batch_size]
        target_batch = target[start_i:start_i + batch_size]

        yield np.array(source_batch), np.array(target_batch)
                   
batch_x, batch_y = batch_data(x_trainr, train_labels, batch_size)
```

My training data consists of 16 x 16 images represented with labels in the first column and 256 columns of pixel values.  Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3srav6i3zuwvno/train-data3.txt?dl=0) to the data.

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/rebeccaschley/.spyder-py3/test.py", line 34, in <module>
    batch_x, batch_y = batch_data(x_trainr, train_labels, batch_size)

  File "/Users/rebeccaschley/.spyder-py3/test.py", line 25, in batch_data
    target = target[shuffle_indices]

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2908, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1254, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)

  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1298, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([5912, 2709, 3697, 3110, 3859, 5057, 1497, 5910, 5715, 1578,\n            ...\n             216,  171, 6031,  785, 4474, 3166, 2547, 5418, 3759, 4723],\n           dtype='int64', length=6292)] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: Is `target` and `source` pandas series or ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `train.label` and `train_pixels` to a numpy array with [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html), this will allow you to use `reshape` directly over `train_pixels`. On your `batch_data` function change `np.arange(len(target))` to `np.arange(target.shape[0])` to generate the batches using the maximum number of lines in the file. No need to use `np.array` in the yield command as the variables still remain as numpy arrays. Next, use the generator to obtain the batches of image (`(250, 16, 16, 1)`) and labels (`(250,)`).

```py
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# reading CSV file
train = pd.read_csv("train-data3.txt")
print(train.shape)
# (6292, 257)

# convert to numpy array
train_labels = train.label.to_numpy()
train_pixels = train.drop('label', 1).to_numpy()

IMG_SIZE=16
x_trainr = train_pixels.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)

batch_size = 250

def batch_data(source, target, batch_size):

    # use target shape[0] to get number of lines
    shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(target.shape[0]))
    source = source[shuffle_indices]
    target = target[shuffle_indices]

    for batch_i in range(0, len(source)//batch_size):
        start_i = batch_i * batch_size
        source_batch = source[start_i:start_i + batch_size]
        target_batch = target[start_i:start_i + batch_size]

        yield source_batch, target_batch

batch_output = batch_data(x_trainr, train_labels, batch_size)

for img, label in batch_output:
    print(img.shape)
    print(label.shape)
```

Output

```py
(250, 16, 16, 1)
(250,)
(250, 16, 16, 1)
(250,)
...
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response.  It was very helpful and it solved my problem.